# send data from Bootstrap modal to Flask backend

Tags: flask, bootstrap-modal

I'm quite new to web development, so I have a question regarding sending gathered data from bootstrap modal to flask :
here is the Bootstrap modal :

```
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id = "ManageOpps" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;" method="POST">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.Customer.label }} {{ form.Customer (class_='form-control', required='required')}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.ProjectId.label }} {{ form.ProjectId(class_='form-control', required='required')}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.PartName.label }} {{ form.PartName (class_='form-control', required='required')}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.Quantity.label }} {{ form.Quantity (class_='form-control', required='required')}}
                </div>
                {{ form.submit(class_='btn btn-primary', style_='margin: 10%;') }}
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="clean()">Clean Data</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
```

However, when I click on submission field, it seems that the data is cleaned up ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `form` tag adds this:

```
<form id="ManageOpps" style="your style here" action="" method="POST" novalidate>
```